# SQL converting datetime from 23:59:50 to 00:00:00

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a function that retrieves some data between a date range. I pass two date range as starting date and ending date.

- StartDate: { 18/06/2020 00:00:00 } -> fromDate
- EndDate: { 18/06/2020 23:59:59 } -> toDate

In my SQL query, I am doing the following:

```
public List<User> GetUsers(DateTime fromDate, DateTime toDate) 
{
     const string query = @"SELECT 
                                Username, age, address,
                                @fromDate AS ExecutedFromDate,
                                @toDate AS ExecutedToDate
                            FROM 
                                [Customer].[dbo].[People]
                            WHERE 
                                CreatedDate > @fromDate AND TransactionDate < @toDate";
}

var result = await Connection.QueryAsync<Users>(query, new { fromDate = from, toDate = to });
```

My problem is that I want ExecutedFromDate to have the value of `{18/06/2020 00:00:00}` and that ExecutedToDate the value of `{18/06/2020 23:59:59}`

SQL is omitting the time, and making it as 00:00:00. Please help

Comment: Hi, what is your database ? Oracle, MySQL, SQLSERVER ?

Comment: Can you show how you add the parameters to the query in GetUsers?

Comment: As you are using `TransactionDate < @toDate`, maybe use `19/6/2020 0:00:00` as enddate?

Comment: you are comparing different dates  for from and to, is this intended?

Comment: SQL server. I need the dates that I have passed as parameters in my result set also,

Comment: @HansKeﬆing: I edited the question

Comment: Could it be you meant 'ExecutedToDate' when you wrote 'ExecutedDate'?

Comment: @Turo: YEs that's right.

Comment: It's not clear from your example what values your are passing to your function. It should be as easy in C# to calc your desired value with ```DateTime executedToDate = ExecutedFromDate.AddDays(1).AddSeconds(-1);```

Answer (score 0):

You can.

```
const string query = @"SELECT 
                                    Username, age, address,
                                    @fromDate AS ExecutedFromDate,
                                    @toDate AS ExecutedToDate
                                FROM 
                                    [Customer].[dbo].[People]
                                WHERE 
                                    CreatedDate > @fromDate AND TransactionDate < DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, @toDate, '23:59:59');
```

But it is not good. The best way for you is put toDate = {18/06/2020 23:59:59}